# How to format a decimal (floating point) number parameter in url

Tags: http, url, floating-point

Is there a specification about how decimal numbers have to be formatted, when transmitted as a parameter in an URL:

`e.g. http://example.org?value=1234.5` vs.
`e.g. http://example.org?value=1234,5`

Or does this depend on the server implementation? This question arises cause of some countries using comma, some a dot.

Update: I am not interested in how to urlencode the value, but how to format the decimal number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a specification about how decimal numbers have to be formatted, when transmitted as a parameter in an URL

No.

It totally depends on the server implementation.

You may want to accept both variations from clients with different region/language/culture settings, or you could do the conversion on client side (unreliable in a web environment though, as JavaScript could be turned off) and have the server expect one specific standard.

If expecting one specific standard, it's probably not a bad idea to default to the anglo notation (1234.56) and store that internally, given that our programming environments, libraries, etc. are extremely anglo-centric as well.

When outputting the information again, format it if necessary according to the client's region/culture/language settings.

Comment: As an additionial argument, in the [OData specification](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#PrimitiveDataTypes), Edm.Decimal, Edm.Single and Edm.Double values are define with a dot.

Answer (score 3):

> A decimal mark is a symbol used to separate the integer part from the
>   fractional part of a number written in decimal form.
>
> Different countries officially designate different symbols for the
>   decimal mark. The choice of symbol for the decimal mark also affects
>   the choice of symbol for the thousands separator used in digit
>   grouping, so the latter is also treated in this article.
>
> — Wikipedia: [Decimal mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark)

If you are **using a floating point URL parameter for some sort of programmatic calculation** so it is a common practice to **format it the way it works** which in most cases is the format with a dot `.` notation because `,` is not used in programmatic calculations as a decimal point.

**Check:** you can check some popular websites like Amazon, eBay, Shopify and others where all of them are using `.` not the `,`.

If you are just **showing it as a content** or getting it from an endpoint to **show it later as a content or printed (not for the purpose of programmatic calculation)** then you should take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) Wikipedia article where all the countries and their appropriate usage of the number formatting is available so **you could show it according to these designations**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I cannot see, how this explains how a decimal number has to be formatted, when transmitting as a paramter of a query in an URL.

Comment: I have updated my answer hope it to solve your confusion.